# For loop to extract data scattered across multiple columns in another R dataframe

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I have a survey question in which respondents could select multiple answers (for 16 possible combinations, e.g. "Which color do you like?" can result in responses "red, blue, green, yellow" or "red, blue, green, black" etc.

These 16 possible combinations are contained in a spreadsheet:

[Image 1: First two rows of the spreadsheet (full spreadsheet has 16 rows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK19i.png)

Example 1:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("red", "ruby"), class = "factor"), 
V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", "violet"), class = "factor"), 
V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("green", "turqoise"), class = "factor"), 
V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("black", "yellow"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

The dataframe with responses has sixteen columns for this question (one column per every simple combination of colors). If respondent 1 selected the first combination, only the first column contains data; similarly, if respondent 2 selected the second combination, the second column contains data. The other are empty:

[Image 2: The first two columns of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnx5Z.png)

Example 2:

```
structure(list(respondentID = 1:16, v1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
v4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), v5 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v6 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v8 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), v9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), v10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v12 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA
), v13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA), v14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v16 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L
)), .Names = c("respondentID", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", 
"v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12", "v13", "v14", "v15", 
"v16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

(Of course, in practice respondent 1 didn't necessarily choose combination 1).

All the information in the dataframe is the number "1", which corresponds to appropriate combination in the spreadsheet.

In order to analyze responses to the question, I need to extract the combination from the spreadsheet and import it into the dataframe with responses, so that I get four new columns in the dataframe with the combination of colors chosen by a respondent (e.g. red, blue, green, yellow for respondent 1).

I don't think there's any way to do this using apply, so I guess I need to write a for loop to extract and import the data. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data aren't very helpful.

Comment: The second data frame you posted has 9 columns plus the IDs, not 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the second data frame into a long shape, you can filter for just the combinations each person chose, and then join the second data frame with the first. The two data frames have combination labels that can be reconciled between the two to join on.

Note that I changed the column names in the first data frame, `df1_with_id`, to be `color1`, etc, only because otherwise you would have `v1`, `v2`, ... in one data frame, and `V1`, `V2`, ... representing something different in the other. Not a necessary change, but it's good to keep from confusing what different variables mean.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("red", "ruby"), class = "factor"),V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", "violet"), class = "factor"),V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("green", "turqoise"), class = "factor"),V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("black", "yellow"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1","V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

df2 <- structure(list(respondentID = 1:16, v1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 1L, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v3 = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),v4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA,NA, NA, NA), v5 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v6 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v8 = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA), v10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v12 = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), v13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, 1L, NA, NA), v14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), v16 = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("respondentID", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5","v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12", "v13", "v14", "v15","v16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

df1_with_id <- df1 %>% 
    setNames(paste0("color", 1:4)) %>%
    mutate(combo = paste0("v", row_number()))

head(df1_with_id)
#>   color1 color2   color3 color4 combo
#> 1    red   blue    green yellow    v1
#> 2    red   blue    green  black    v2
#> 3    red   blue turqoise yellow    v3
#> 4    red   blue turqoise  black    v4
#> 5    red violet    green yellow    v5
#> 6    red violet    green  black    v6

df2 %>%
    gather(key = combo, value = val, -respondentID) %>%
    filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
    left_join(df1_with_id, by = "combo")
#>    respondentID combo val color1 color2   color3 color4
#> 1             1    v1   1    red   blue    green yellow
#> 2             2    v2   1    red   blue    green  black
#> 3             7    v3   1    red   blue turqoise yellow
#> 4             4    v4   1    red   blue turqoise  black
#> 5            11    v4   1    red   blue turqoise  black
#> 6            12    v4   1    red   blue turqoise  black
#> 7             3    v5   1    red violet    green yellow
#> 8             2    v6   1    red violet    green  black
#> 9            10    v6   1    red violet    green  black
#> 10            5    v7   1    red violet turqoise yellow
#> 11            6    v8   1    red violet turqoise  black
#> 12            8    v9   1   ruby   blue    green yellow
#> 13            9   v11   1   ruby   blue turqoise yellow
#> 14           13   v12   1   ruby   blue turqoise  black
#> 15           14   v13   1   ruby violet    green yellow
#> 16           16   v16   1   ruby violet turqoise  black
```

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: The code works and correctly connects the responses in example 2 dataframe to combinations in example 1 dataframe. However, the code simply copies the appropriate combination, so that, e.g. "red,blue,green,yellow" forms one column, instead of being split across four color-specific columns. I'm also having trouble recreating your code with the corrected dataframe (which I posted above in the edited question). Specifically, I'm trying to avoid reusing the ifelse, but can't find a way to rewrite the code without recreating the "combo" variable.

Comment: I hadn't seen the updated data when I posted. You don't have to paste the colors together into one column—it seems more manageable to me that way, but isn't necessary. The `ifelse` bit was because there weren't unified labels otherwise—that's no longer needed since you have cleaner labels. I'll update now

Comment: This works great. Thank you, @camille. The only thing I might add for anyone who might encounter this question in the future is to add "arrange(respondentID)" to the code. For most uses I imagine it will be more convenient to retain the row numbers (as in, corresponding to respondents) from the original dataset (in this question example 2 dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. Using the tidyverse packages and the melt() function of the reshape2 package, you might try

```
df_respondent_combination <-
  df_respondent %>%
  melt(measure.vars = c(2:ncol(.)), na.rm = T) %>%
  cbind(df_combination) %>%
  select(-variable, -value) %>%
  arrange(respondentID)
```

With df_respondent_combination the new dataframe expected, df_respondent your example 2 and df_combination your example 1.

Comment: Thank you. This might potentially be the way forward, but as it is I'm getting error messages because the two dataframes have different numbers of rows. The number of rows in dataframes shouldn't matter for what I'm trying to do as the point is to detect which column in df_respondent indicates response and then use the number of that column to extract the response combination from the row with the same number from df_combination.

Comment: As @camille has helpfully pointed out, the example 2 only had 9 columns. (I've amended the code.) Even with the correct 16 columns, something about your code isn't working, Jrmie. I can execute the code, and get a dataframe in just the right format, but the variables don't correspond to choices actually made by respondents. For example, according to df_respondent_combination, respondent 10 chose "ruby, blue, green, yellow", while in the actual example respondent 10 chose "red, violet, green, black".